# Spring property loading - decrypting encrypted properties on the fly

Tags: java, spring, encryption, properties

I'm using the latest property loading mechanism exposed by spring- PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, and trying to decrypt the encrypted properties on the fly. Will PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer I could override resolvePlaceholder, and add the decryption mechanism to it.

However, I can't figure out how to do it in PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. Have tried overriding processProperties, and passing in my custom ConfigurablePropertyResolver[with getProperty Overriden] but this doesn't work.

```
MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();

try {
    propertySources.addFirst(getExtendPortsProperties());
    propertySources.addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:/X.properties"));
    propertySources.addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:/Y.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("failed to read property source", e);
}
```

This is how I read the properties. And then,

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer result = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
result.setPropertySources(firePropertiesSources);
```

That's how I set the properties.

Now, one of the properties in these props is encrypted, and I need to to instruct Spring to decrypt that before substituting placeholders with the actual values.[I need to specify my custom implementation]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your own, have you looked at jasypt? It has the exact functionality you need. Have a look at http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html

Comment: Thanks David. This serves my purpose.

Comment: I've added this to my project, and it seems to be doing its job; however, in case of exceptions, it's not giving me the right message. For example- <bean id=abc p:password=${pwd}/>, and if pwd is encrypted incorrectly, jasypt should give me a meaningful - Encyption*** exception, but it doesn't. I'm using "EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource" for decryption. I add all my files as EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource, and then use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. Any pointers?